# Python Selenium download file from non-unique id

Tags: python, selenium

Hopefully, someone will have some idea on how to do this.

I just got started with Selenium and have a very specific task to perform. I upload a file of one format to a free online service which converts it into another one and redirects me to a page where I can download the converted file, but I have to click on a button or link to do that. (For the record I can't use a converter to do this as the service adds info to the file, not only converts the file type)

The issue is that the URL of the page containing the converted file is a generic one 
(e.g. `https://www.something.com/convert?output`) and when I try to get Selenium to search for a file there it just goes to that generic link with no output, instead of staying on the redirected page with the file.

I know there is an option to make the driver wait for the page to load and then proceed to do tasks, but as far as I understand it still needs a new URL, which would just end up the same.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"download.default_directory": "/home/marko/files"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/marko/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("url of the converting site")

choose_file = driver.find_element_by_name('uploaded_file_1')

file_location = "/home/marko/file.original"

choose_file.send_keys(file_location)

get_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Convert & add']").click()

driver.get("https://www.something.com/convert?output") -> here's the trouble

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("following link").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply let the web redirect you to the page with the link or download button.

What you need to do is make the browser wait. For this you can use:

- **Implicit wait** (`driver.implicitly_wait(seconds)`): This adds a wait every time you search for an item. Especially useful when the machine or connection is slow.
- **Explicit wait** (with `WaitWebDriver()`): Wait for a condition until a certain timeout time. Especially useful when you wait for a long process whose time is not according to the rest of the page load.

So, using an explicit wait, the code would look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# New imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

preferences = {"download.default_directory": "/home/marko/files"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/marko/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get("url of the converting site")

choose_file = driver.find_element_by_name('uploaded_file_1')

file_location = "/home/marko/file.original"

choose_file.send_keys(file_location)

get_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Convert & add']").click()

# Once the process is started, wait for the element to be clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) # Adjust the timeout seconds to a reasonable max time for the process
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'following link')))

element.click()
```

You can learn more and find more waiting conditions [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code works great now! I misunderstood the problem. I thought that if I didn't provide the link, the page previous to the redirection would be searched, instead of following the redirection. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you providing another URL?

**The reason for the blank page is that it has not been processed yet.**

If the service is converting something, it would take time and will automatically redirect you. The reason behind this is that the server is converting that and it will automatically show the output. Don't give any second link. Instead of that, wait for the redirection. You can use implicit wait or simply use "sleep"

Use of implicit is already described. Here's how to use sleep.

```
import time
time.sleep(4) # the time is in seconds
```

By the way, can you provide me the link you are using? It could help you better.